# char array to String, can't use in if-statement

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, char

```
char[] Char = {'a','b'};
String str = "ab";

String c = new String(Char);

if(str == c){
    System.out.println("working!");
}
```

I've converted the array "Char" to a String "c" but when i try to use it in the if-statement it's nor working. Nothing prints out and no erors.

Help please!

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string contents, not the `==` operator.

Comment: Use equal method .. something like this string1.equals(string2)..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equals()` instead of `==` for `String`s:

```
char[] Char = {'a','b'};
String str = "ab";

String c = new String(Char);

if(str.equals(c)){
    System.out.println("working!");
}
```